# Missing camera roll permission in expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, permissions, expo

I have "Change Image" button and I want to user camera roll to change the image.
But I get warning that I don't have permission to use camera roll.
How do I check if permission is granted or not? If it is not I want to ask for permission.

This is my code for now:

```js
    _pickImage = async () => {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
          allowsEditing: true,
          aspect: [4, 3],
        });
    
        console.log(result);
    
        if (!result.cancelled) {
          this.setState({ image: result.uri });
        }
    };
```

This may be very dumb question but I am bit confused here...

If you need any more information please comment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are using Expo you can get `Permission` from Expo. follow their docs, its great!

It would look something like this:

```
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';

async componentDidMount() {
  const permission = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
  if (permission.status !== 'granted') {
      const newPermission = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
      if (newPermission.status === 'granted') {
        //its granted.
      }
  } else {
   ....your code
  }
}
```

Link to [Expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v29.0.0/sdk/permissions)

I edited with some new code. You could just use `askAsync` entirely, you decide. The docs are very helpful!

Comment: First, can you edit "permissions.status" to "permission.status" , that "s" is extra, second, so it is checking correctly, but how do I ask for permission, so that alert comes where you press "Accept" or "Deny"?

Comment: I edited my comment, maybe that can help you a bit more

Comment: Oh it worked... I forgot to make it correct answer. Thanks btw!

Comment: Do you really need to call `getAsync`, I presume `askAsync` will only ask if permission are not provided.